# Adding text to my div shifts my div down

Tags: html, css

You can see in the image below that there is a space on my div on top part of the page; I don't want any space. When I add the text the div automatically shifts down. I want my text to align right in the center of the div, and my div not to have any space on top.

[image: Screenshot of a grey div near the top of the page with an email address in it. There is a small amount of white space above the div.]

I tried to do `vertical-align: top;` on my div id, and nothing will move everything stays the same. I tried to add `position: absolute` and that won't work either. Am I missing something else?

Here's my code:

```css
#topbar {
  background: url(img/topbarbg.jpg);
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.email {
  font-family: 'Futura', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="topbar">
    <p class="email">info@erdosmiller.com</p>
  </div>

</header>


<div id="hero">
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we can see where your problem is. See [how-to-ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: im sorry i added an image to the post but this is the text:                         topbar {
  background: url(img/topbarbg.jpg);
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.email {
  font-family: 'Futura', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  }

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML?

Comment: Yes not a problem.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: *shifts my div down* -  Are you talking about the white space right above the div in your 2nd screenshot?

Comment: In my 2nd image that i just uploaded you can see that there is a space on my div on top part of the page, which i dont want any space. When i add the text the div automatically shifts down. I want my text to align right in the center of the div, and my div not to have any space on top.

Comment: Correct BSMP. Thats my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reset `padding` & `margin`s like this & set `line-height` to vertically align text:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#topbar {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
  height: 40px;
  /* vertical-align: top; */
}
.email {
  font-family: 'Futura', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="topbar">
    <p class="email">info@erdosmiller.com</p>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="hero">
</div>
```

Comment: If the OP finds they need to reset all the CSS styles, there is a list of popular CSS resets here: http://cssreset.com/